# How could I run -exec on find command after | grep

Tags: grep, find, exec

I am on a remote machine attempting to move all `loader.gif` files into a `/Pictures` folder

`find . -iname *.gif | grep loader` shows four file I would like to move, naturally I tried: `find . -iname *.gif | grep loader -exec cp *.gif /home/me/`

How could I copy all files matching my criteria of `loader.gif` through a `find` and a `grep` command? (I am using `grep` because the original find command results show ALL `.gif` files, but I only desire `loader.gif` filenames)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNUly:

```
find . -iname '*.gif' -print0 | grep -z loader | xargs -r0 cp -t /home/me
```

POSIXly:

```
find . -name '*.[gG][iI][fF]' -path '*loader*' -exec sh -c '
  exec cp "$@" /home/me' sh {} +
```

(I used `-path` so it be equivalent with the `grep` solution, but it sounds like you want `loader` to be found in the name of the file as opposed to its directory components, in which case you should use `-name` instead).

Note that `-iname '*.gif'` may fail to match on a `.GIF` in a locale where uppercase `i` is `İ` instead of `I` (like Turkish locales on GNU systems).

Comment: What is the significance of loader after grep, I do not see `loader` in `man grep`

Answer (score 1):

I think `xargs` is the more simple and direct solution:

```
find . -iname *.gif | grep loader | xargs cp -t /home/me
```

Comment: That assumes none of the file names contain blanks (the list of which depends on the locale and the xargs implementation), newline, single quote, double quote or backslash characters.